# Using ActiveModel::Serializer to render JSON for jQuery DataTable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, active-model-serializers

I am trying to convert an index view in my rails app to use jQuery datatables, with server-side data processing to search, sort, and paginate the record set, which will be rendered by ActiveModel::Serializer

The DataTable requires a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{ 
  draw: 1,
  iTotalRecords: @records_count,
  iTotalDisplayRecords: @records_filtered_count,
  sEcho: params[:sEcho],
  aaData: [ 
    [ <column 1 value>, <column 2 value>, etc ],
    [ <column 1 value>, <column 2 value>, etc ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

Currently I'm rendering that in a view template called index.json.haml. It looks like this:

```
= raw({ draw: 1,
  iTotalRecords: 1000,
  iTotalDisplayRecords: 100,
  sEcho: params[:sEcho],
  aaData: [ 
    [ <column 1 value>, <column 2 value>, etc ],
    [ <column 1 value>, <column 2 value>, etc ],
    ...
  ] }.to_json)
```

I'm trying to do this JSON rendering in a serializer so that I could get rid of the view template and just add the following to my controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render json: @my_objects, serializer: MyObjectsSerializer
    end
  end
end
```

So far this is what my serializer looks like:

```
class AssetDetailTitlesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :draw, :iTotalRecords, :iTotalDisplayRecords, :sEcho, :aaData

  def draw
    1
  end

  def iTotalRecords
    1000
  end

  def iTotalDisplayRecords
    100
  end

  def sEcho
    'what is this'
  end

  def aaData
    object.map do |my_object|
      [
        my_object.<column 1 getter>,
        my_object.<column 2 getter>,
        etc.
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

of course I will have real values for iTotalRecords, etc, but my main issue is that I'm calling helpers to generate the content in each of the fields - for example, one column is a link that needs to call a rails path/url helper. Other columns are calling a helper that highlights text that matches a search query. 
These helpers are not available in the serializer, and also call `params` which doesn't make sense outside of the view/controller.

My problem is that all these calls to view helpers are entangled in my serializer code. It was not an issue when I was rendering the JSON in index.json.haml, because that's where view logic belongs. So my question is: is this even a good use of a serializer? My goal was to clean up my views and controller, but right now I've just pushed the mess to another object where it'll be an even bigger mess (assuming I can get it to work at all)